# Grafana display of values curl command line return different values for the same query

Tags: kubernetes, influxdb, grafana

We are using kubernetes, which is collecting data in influxdb. The values in influx are displayed in grafana.

For a new dashboard we are creating, we are using the queries from grafana and implemented them in node.js. The queries in node however return values 2x the values as displayed in grafana.

The query we are using to test is:

```
q=SELECT SUM(\"value\") FROM \"cpu/usage_rate\" WHERE time > now() - 5m 
AND \"pod_namespace\" =~ /ournamespace/ 
AND \"pod_name\" =~ /ourSinglePod/   GROUP BY time(1m)
```

Curl version for easy reproduction:

```
curl -G http://10.144.1.5:8086/query?pretty=true --data-urlencode "db=k8s" --data-urlencode "q=SELECT SUM(\"value\") FROM \"cpu/usage_rate\" WHERE time > now() - 5m AND \"pod_namespace\" =~ /adserving/ AND \"pod_name\" =~ /ads-357196871-qek76/   GROUP BY time(1m)"
```

Results:

```
{
    "results": [
        {
            "series": [
                {
                    "name": "cpu/usage_rate",
                    "columns": [
                        "time",
                        "sum"
                    ],
                    "values": [
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:51:00Z",
                            null
                        ],
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:52:00Z",
                            156
                        ],
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:53:00Z",
                            162
                        ],
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:54:00Z",
                            148
                        ],
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:55:00Z",
                            156
                        ],
                        [
                            "2017-01-26T18:56:00Z",
                            154
                        ]
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

The values displayed in graphs in grafana are half of these values.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what the issue is.

Comment: @MichaelDesa The values displayed in grafana are only half of the values queried from influxdb using the same query as grafana. Since I copy/paste the queries from grafana, I would expect the same results.

Comment: Can you include a screen grab of the Grafana?

Comment: @MichaelDesa the thing is that the values displayed on a graph are made automaticly smaller by grafana. they change to normal when you change date range. I cannot find why.